# python tkinter font size cross platform

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter so I am not sure if this is expected behavior. I imagined that not everything would be the exact same but it seems strange that the font would be bigger? (*I am using mac os mojave and linux ubuntu 17.10 with all default gnome desktop env*)

edit: I tried to change the `TkDefaultFont` into something different (*which was `Times` as I have both on mac and linux*) but the size still makes a difference

all of the font-size is done by the Style class, except the text frame.

```
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('audio.TLabel', font=('TkDefaultFont', 15))
```

snippets of the of the visibile parts that are affected:

```
# Top Label
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('top.TLabel', font=('TkDefaultFont', 40))

top = ttk.Frame(self, width=1000, height=50)
top.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3)

# Text Frame
text_frame = ttk.Frame(self, width=1000, height=220)
text_frame.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=3, sticky=tk.N)
text_frame.grid_propagate(False)
self._text_box = tk.Text(text_frame, width=43, height=7,
                         borderwidth=1, relief='sunken',
                         font=('TkDefaultFont', 25))
self._text_box.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=tk.N)

# Audio Options
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('audio.TLabel', font=('TkDefaultFont', 15))
audio_label = ttk.LabelFrame(audio, text='Audio Options')
audio_label.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=3)

# HTML frame
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('text.TLabel', font=('TkDefaultFont', 35))
self._html_label = ttk.LabelFrame(html, text='HTML')
self._html_label.grid(column=0, row=0)
# XXX linux font seems to be of a different size
self._text_html = tk.Text(self._html_label, width=10, height=1,
                          font=('TkDefaultFont', 20))
self._text_html.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, pady=5)
```

and so on. Pretty much ordinary stuff

is there something I can do to prevent this?

mac:
[image]

linux:
the text-widget is so much bigger that pushes part of the gui off screen

[image]

linux after i tweak the font size to make it smaller just to be certain that it is the font size that is different (the screenshot doesn't cut the gui, but the frame is actually outside the gui frame):

[image]

Comment: Could you bit a bit more clear about what part of those screenshots is relevant? You have lots of text with at least two different sizes. Are you talking about the size of the header ("Podcast Tools 2")?

Comment: I've update a picture. all of the elements that are circled are using a style font-size. the first picture it is how it should look. then the second picture its how it looks on linux. the third picture is how it looks if I adjust the font size on linux. the third picture is just for saying that the font size is the one that makes things look different

Comment: Are you more concerned about the actual font size, or is the real problem that the larger font messes up the layout? If the layout didn’t get messed up, do you really care about the font?

Comment: Though, I guess there isn’t enough information for us to help with the layout. It’s a solvable problem, it’s just not entirely which problem you are really wanting to solve?

Comment: @VirgilSisoe: Let's focus at the header, seems only `Label` affected. [Edit] your Question and show the relevant code line `Label(...` and all `<label>.configure(...` if any. Also tell, did you use any `Theme` and which window manager on linux?

Comment: Try not using `TkDefaultFont` as it may be alias to other font which may be different in different platforms.  Try using font like `Arial` which is available in most platforms.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am concerned about the layout. if the font is just a bit different thats ok, but as you can see in the second picture the text widget (because uses a bigger font size) it actually pushing out off the screen the frame next to it.

Comment: everything that uses the argument font=('TkDefaultFont', size) is affected, while some may be not much different from the original you can actually see the second picture where (because of the font) one of the frame is actually off screen. I will edit and add the relevant code. I have not specified a theme so it should be is using the default

Comment: @acw1668 if I change the TkDefaultFont to something else, it does something (on the mac goes smaller and also on linux) but they are still not the same. But it seems a good point to check, I may have to find an exact font on both platform and check. Didnt now have Arial btw had to install it and it didnt not made any difference